# Is event in specified date in Apple calendar by AppleScript?

Tags: events, applescript

I need to test if in specified day has any events in the built-in Apple Calendar app. Here is my current idea as pseudocode:

```
// input variables
day_to_test = 23
month_to_test = 8
year_to_test = 2016
testing_date = day_to_test + month_to_test + year_to_test as date

// actual "code"
if testing_date has any event in Apple calendar Then
   display dialog "There is any event on that day!"
else
   display dialog "Free of events!"
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Main" -- national holiday calendar in my iCloud 
        set today to current date
        set today's year to 2013
        set today's month to 3
        set today's day to 5
        set today's time to 0
        copy (today + days) to tomorrow
        set currentEvents to events whose start date ≥ today and end date ≤ tomorrow
    end tell
end tell
```